# Is there a way to independently use the left and right sides of the drag event?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

In Unreal's blueprint, I want to use the right and left sides of the UI Canvas in different ways. This can happen separately, but it can also be used at the same time. While currently using the left drag, the drag event for the left calls the drop event the moment you press the right. Is there a way to maintain the drag event for the left even if you press the right side while using the left drag?

Answer (score 0):

You can make  two different onDrop arena ;; you can make 1 and pick function based on drop position using pointer event ;; you can use in smart way onDrop run priority or you can make other way.